# Airtable gatsby source plugin with gatsby image

Tags: gatsby, airtable

So I'm using gatsby-source-airtable to pull images from my airtable.

In my gastby-config I've mapped my attachment column as filenode:

`mapping: {'image':fileNode}`,

In GraphiQL gatsby image plugins seem to be working
This query:

```
{
airtable(table: {
    eq: "table-1"
}, data: {
    slug: {
        eq: "test-1"
    }
}) {
    data {
        image {
            localFiles {
                childImageSharp {
                    fluid(maxWidth: 400) {
                        src
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Provides this response:

```
{
"data": {
    "airtable": {
        "data": {
            "image": {
                "localFiles": [{
                    "childImageSharp": {
                        "fluid": {
                            "src": "/static/08baa0d1735184a4d0dd141d90f564d4-28158c2eb0b0b748efeabc0ec551c623-7eb65.jpg"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and then going to that src generates the image and appears in browser.

However when i try use this with gatsby-image:

```
<Img fluid={post.data.image.localFiles.childImageSharp.fluid} />

    export const query = graphql query PostQuery {
    airtable(table: {
        eq: "table-1"
    }, data: {
        slug: {
            eq: "test-1"
        }
    }) {
        data {
            image {
                localFiles {
                    childImageSharp {
                        fluid(maxWidth: 400) { ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fluid' of undefined

What am i doing something wrong? Any assistant would be appreciated

Comment: Quick question is this Gatsby Verison 1 or 2. Also, have you read this [ tutorial](https://blog.airtable.com/build-your-own-custom-blog-cms-with-airtable-and-gatsbyjs/) It examples using images from Airtable its part of an attachment field in the Table.

Comment: Are any of the properties in your chain (post.data.image.localFiles.childImageSharp.fluid) collections? e.g. is localFiles an array of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying the `localFiles` field on `image` will give you an array. Test the query in GraphiQL:

> Note that you'll have to replace the `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` fragment (not supported by GraphiQL) with another field like `src`

```
airtable(table: {
  eq: "table-1"
}, data: {
  slug: {
    eq: "test-1"
  }
}) {
  data {
    image {
      localFiles {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 400) {
            src
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should get something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "airtable": {
      "data": {
        "image": {
          "localFiles": [
            {
              "childImageSharp": {
                "fluid": {
                  "src": "/static/8a6a13a2664ef8330843b7855ad2c5e2/d278e/o.jpg"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, `localFiles` is an array, so in your component you should write:

```html
<Img fluid={post.data.image.localFiles[0].childImageSharp.fluid} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing data to one of your gatsby image components so it throws an error. Try clicking around your pages while running `gatsby develop` to see where this is happening. Also, any error reports or log would be helpful.